# Make one elemenet of grid (gradually) disappear?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How can I animate **grid-template-areas** property? I want bottom column to disappear when width is more than **1000px**. This code does nothing and I can't make it work. The elements stay where they are.

```css
.header_nav_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "top"
    "botom";
}

.top_row {
  grid-area: top;
}

.bottom_row {
  grid-area: botom;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .header_nav_container {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top"
      "botom";
    color: blue;
    transition: all 300ms;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .header_nav_container {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top";
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header_nav_container">
    <div class="top_row">
      TOP ROW CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_row">
      BOTTOM ROW CONTENT
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want bottom column to disappear when width is more than 1000px

Just add to your CSS

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .bottom_row {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and that's all